# Rewrite rules for redirect URLs using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using `.htaccess` to redirect URLs on my website to avoid having links like for example page1.php.

I have a subfolder `engine/index.php` on the root domain that i intend to use to process the redirected URL.

e.g i want the link `localhost/user` to rewrite to `localhost/engine/index.php?view=user`
NOTE:The links being used i.e /user is not a file or folder existing on the domain

Comment: Have you tried writing any rule so far?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ engine/index.php?view=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Put this in your `.htaccess` file directly in your `www/` directory.
`([a-z]+)` will match a group of letters (also capitals since the `NC` flag is used), but if something else than a letter is behind `localhost/` the url won't be rewritten. If there are only letters behind `localhost`, the url will rewritten to `engine/index.php?view=$1`

The `L` flag indicates that this is the last `RewriteRule`, and the `QSA` flag appends the old querystring to the new one. For example: `localhost/user?var=val` will redirect to `localhost/engine/index.php?view=user&var=val`.

**But**, if the user goes to `localhost/user?view=somethingelse`, it will be rewritten to `localhost/engine/index.php?view=user&view=somethingelse` which means that if you do `$_GET['view']` in `engine.php`, **it will return "somethingelse"**. To get the first `view` parameter from the querystring (`user`), use this regex in PHP:

```
$view = preg_replace('/view=([^&]+).*/', '$1', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); //now, $view contains 'user'
```

Comment: I was using RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /engine/index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]. Not sure why it was not working.

Comment: @jmsiox possibly because of the `/` in front of `/engine/index.php?p=$1`. Also see my updated answer for how to prevent the user from setting the `view` parameter manually

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is it better now? ;)